# Settings the max value on Kendo UI Slider dynamically

Tags: jquery, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am playing with Kendo UI and created a slider. The limits of the slider will be min16 max 80 when I create it via Razor.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Slider()
     .Name("Age")
     .Value(16)                    
     .Min(18).Max(80).LargeStep(50).SmallStep(1).TickPlacement(SliderTickPlacement.None).ShowButtons(false)
     .Events(
        e => e.Change("AgeSliderChanged"))
        )
```

However, say you selected something else on the form that means that the maximum value has to change (I.e. Max comes down to 50 instead of 80). How can this be done in javascript?

I am used to the jQueryUI library so where you can do this:

`$("#Age").slider("option","max", 50);` and it magically resizes the slider for you.

However, I tried a similar approach in Kendo and got nowhere. Upon looking in Chrome Devtools I found the options/max setting: `$("#Age").data("kendoSlider").options.max`

If I try this:
`$("#d2cRequired").data("kendoSlider").options.max = 50`, it returns "50" and sets the limit on the Kendo slider to 50 (i.e. If I set it to 51 it jumps back to 50)
although this works, ideally I want to know if you can resize the slider like jqueryUI? (Is this even the correct way to change the max limit of the slider?!) Their documentation is very hit and miss and doesn't really show any examples of changing the options dynamically (other than value setting)

I am evaluating Kendo as a possible use in the company and don't want to spend thousands if some of their components don't work any better than JQUI equivalents!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Kendo forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/slider/how-can-i-change-a-property-of-the-slider-after-it-has-been-initialized.aspx), I quote:

> Currently there is no such functionality available. I would suggest to
>   submit your request in [Kendo's UserVoice](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback) so other members of the
>   community can evaluate, comment on and vote for it.

You have a couple of options, have multiple sliders and show the one you want or DESTROY the slider and recreate it.

Comment: Yeah I went with this option in the end. I simply read the current value, stored it and re-created a new slider with the old value persisted and the new changes I wanted.

Comment: Have also created a jsFiddle to show how you can destory and recreate. http://jsfiddle.net/rippo/MJMUZ/